# Can we access iPhone's screen from comp?

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to access my friend's iPhone (in US) from my office (India). 
I used Team Viewer to install my application on his mobile. But I also want to give him a demo. 
I had sent him instructions to operate the app but some how he couldn't understand the output.

Is there a way that i can take access of his iPhone (like the emulator)? So that i can check the output for myself.

Note: It's an app using bluetooth, hence i cannot try it on the emulator. I am using Private API's to access bluetooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in jail-broken device. You will need to install VNC server on your iPhone and then using VNC client from desktop you can access the device screen. See [this](http://www.tuaw.com/2008/09/18/veency-vnc-server-for-iphone/) for more details.For emulator I am not sure if you can do that. Why not do remote desktop on machine running the emulator.

Comment: is jailbreaking safe? I read the warranty goes void after jailbreaking.

Comment: also... after jailbreaking, are we allowed to use App Store? won't it create problems then?

Comment: You can restore your phone to get back to original state :). Jailbreaking does not stop to access appstore and all, every thing remains same :)